# How we can "aws_alb_target_group.tenant[each.key].arn" declare in terraform output value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, foreach, terraform, aws-application-load-balancer

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "test" {
  for_each = var.microservices
  name        = "${each.key}-tg"
  port        = each.value
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  target_type = "ip"

  health_check {
   healthy_threshold   = "3"
   interval            = "30"
   protocol            = "HTTP"
   matcher             = "200"
   timeout             = "3"
   path                = "/"
   unhealthy_threshold = "2"
  }
tags = {
  Name        = "${each.key}-tg"
  }
}



resource "aws_alb_listener" "test" {
 for_each = var.microservices
 load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.main.arn
 port              = "80"
 protocol          = "HTTP"
 default_action {
     target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.test[each.key].arn
     type             = "forward"
    }
 }
```

I have created multiple target groups using for_each for multiple microservice but in output how can take those all target groups arn?

```
output "new_target_group" {
  value = aws_alb_target_group.main[each.key].arn
}
```

I want all target groups arn in my output Kindly help me on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to get a list with all the ARNs, you can use the [`values`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/values) function with the [`splat`](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat) operator as such:

```
output "new_target_group" {
  value = values(aws_alb_target_group.test)[*].arn
}
```

Comment: Thanks its helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` expression to iterate through the object of your exported resource and construct a map with all of the target groups and their associated ARNs:

```
output "new_target_groups" {
  value = { for target_group in aws_alb_target_group.main : target_group.name => target_group.arn }
}
```

and the result will appear like:

```
new_target_groups = { "${each.key}-tg" = <target_group_arn> }
```

with a key-value pair for each target group.

Comment: Or `[ for target_group in aws_alb_target_group.main : target_group.arn ]` if only the ARNs are wanted.

Comment: Fair point. I usually assume in `output` that people want Map so that each value can be referenced.

Comment: Yeah. And the consumer of the output can then use only the values of the map if they want to.